# CommandLine automation problem - VS2005 Team Edition

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, build-automation

I am trying to automate VC++ build via an addIn written using VB.NEt so that we can schedule it using a simple batch file. This addin performs some custom pre-requisites before the build is started. The build is invoked as ...

```
devenv.com /useenv %NEWSOLFILE% /CLEAN %BUILDCONFIG% /OUT %OUTLOGFILE% > nul
```

with appropriate filename substitutions. I am facing problem in the following entry-point:-

```
Public Sub OnConnection(ByVal application As Object, ByVal connectMode As ext_ConnectMode, ByVal addInInst As Object, ByRef custom As Array) Implements IDTExtensibility2.OnConnection
        If connectMode = ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_CommandLine Then
        ' this is always false why??
       End If
End Sub
```

Here the 'connectMode' is never signalled as 'ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_CommandLine' though we invoke the build from command line. Is this another nasty MS bug?

Anyone encountered this before? Are there any patches that i need to apply to VS 2005 to fix this? Or are there any simple workarounds?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i found this on the Internet [Frustrations with VS command-line framework](http://msmvps.com/blogs/carlosq/archive/2007/10/11/frustrations-with-command-line-add-ins-for-visual-studio.aspx)

Its a MS Visual Studio bug. Also, a workaround has been outlined for the ones not willing to upgrade / patch.